# How to Color in Array Remove android?

Tags: android

`arrayList.add(new Item("Item 2", R.drawable.beer, "#3E51B1"));`There are three image text colors. They are arrays. How to remove the color in that array

This arrayList

```
Item =Item 2

image =R.drawable.beer

color =#3E51B1
```

How to remove color array

[image]

Comment: sorry, my english is not good so can you give more information or explain me about your problem?

Comment: There are three image text colors. They are arrays. How to remove the color in that array

Comment: "#3E51B1" how remove

Comment: There are three image text colors. how to remove color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your Item class like this

```
public class Item {

    public String text;
    public int drawable;

    public Item(String text, int drawable) {
        this.text = text;
        this.drawable = drawable;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public int getDrawable() {
        return drawable;
    }

    public void setDrawable(int drawable) {
        this.drawable = drawable;
    }
}
```

and than In your fragment

```
arrayList.add(new Item("Item 1", R.drawable.battle));
        arrayList.add(new Item("Item 2", R.drawable.beer));
        arrayList.add(new Item("Item 3", R.drawable.ferrari));
        arrayList.add(new Item("Item 4", R.drawable.jetpack_joyride));
        arrayList.add(new Item("Item 5", R.drawable.three_d));
        arrayList.add(new Item("Item 6", R.drawable.terraria));
```

and there is also a use of color in `Home Adapter` so change it also , actually you have to **provide a default color** to it or **remove the** `setBackground()` **function**

In setData() function in HomeAdapter

```
public void setData(Item item) {
            this.item = item;
            textView.setText(item.text);
            imageView.setImageResource(item.drawable);
            relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0000000")); //your default color
        }
```

or

```
public void setData(Item item) {
            this.item = item;
            textView.setText(item.text);
            imageView.setImageResource(item.drawable);
        }
```